# how to remove array from another array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
0: {id: 1553825061863, name: "Thai Milk Tea", qty: "1", total_amount: 9500, toppings: 500, …}
1: {id: 1553825061863, name: "Thai Milk Tea", qty: "1", total_amount: 9500, toppings: 500, …}
2: {id: 1553825061863, name: "Thai Milk Tea", qty: "1", total_amount: 9500, toppings: 500, …}
```

I want to remove `0:{}` array in array. how can i remove? and how to find the value of the first item?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: If you want to remove first element, you can use [Array.shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)

Comment: Please elaborate a little more. What is your expected output. If you just want to remove the first use `Array.shift()` or `Array.slice(1)`

Comment: first -> find array element 
second -> delete array element. 
how can i do

Comment: Can you please post the actual code for your data structure?  From what you've posted here it's not clear whether you're dealing with arrays, or with an object with numeric keys.  (Given that you're also describing the internal objects as "arrays" I suspect the external container is also actually an object...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood from your question that you have something like below that you have to remove Array2 from Array1,

```
Array1 = 0: {id: 1553825061863, name: "Thai Milk Tea", qty: "1", total_amount: 9500, toppings: 500, …}
         1: {id: 1553825061863, name: "Thai Milk Tea", qty: "1", total_amount: 9500, toppings: 500, …}
         2: {id: 1553825061863, name: "Thai Milk Tea", qty: "1", total_amount: 9500, toppings: 500, …}

Array2 = 0: {id: 1553825061863, name: "Thai Milk Tea", qty: "1", total_amount: 9500, toppings: 500, …}
```

If so just try as below using the filter function.

```
    var data = Array1; 
    var selectedRows = Array2; 

    var unSelectedRows = [];
    var unSelectedRows = data.filter( function( el ) {
      return !selectedRows.includes( el );
    } );
```

You can get the 1 st and 2nd element in unSelectedRows Array.

Answer (score 1):

Since an array's first element is always index `0`, you can use [`Array.prototype.shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) which removes the first element:

```js
const array = [{
  id: 1553825061863,
  name: "Thai Milk Tea",
  qty: "1",
  total_amount: 9500,
  toppings: 500
}, {
  id: 1553825061863,
  name: "Thai Milk Tea",
  qty: "1",
  total_amount: 9500,
  toppings: 500
}, {
  id: 1553825061863,
  name: "Thai Milk Tea",
  qty: "1",
  total_amount: 9500,
  toppings: 500
}];

let remainingArray = array;
remainingArray.shift();

console.log(remainingArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//try this on your console. You can use the shift operator to shift the first element.
//also to remove the last element use pop
>>var myArr = [{id : 1, name: "A"}, {id: 2, name: "B"}, {id:3, name: "C"}];
undefined
>>myArr.shift(0);
{id: 1, name: "A"}
>>myArr
0: {id: 2, name: "B"}
1: {id: 3, name: "C"}
```

Here is the detailed link about Array.protoType.shift() 
which removes the first element:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple ways of doing that.

#### Using [`shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)

```js
let arr = [{id: 1553825061863, name: "Thai Milk Tea", qty: "1", total_amount: 9500, toppings: 500}, {id: 1553825061863, name: "Thai Milk Tea", qty: "1", total_amount: 9500, toppings: 500}, {id: 1553825061863, name: "Thai Milk Tea", qty: "1", total_amount: 9500, toppings: 500}]

arr.shift();
console.log(arr);
```

**Note**: `shift()` will modify the original array.

#### Using [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)

```js
let arr = [{id: 1553825061863, name: "Thai Milk Tea", qty: "1", total_amount: 9500, toppings: 500}, {id: 1553825061863, name: "Thai Milk Tea", qty: "1", total_amount: 9500, toppings: 500}, {id: 1553825061863, name: "Thai Milk Tea", qty: "1", total_amount: 9500, toppings: 500}]

arr.splice(0,1);
console.log(arr);
```

**Note**: `splice()` will modify the original array.

### Using `slice`

```js
let arr = [{id: 1553825061863, name: "Thai Milk Tea", qty: "1", total_amount: 9500, toppings: 500}, {id: 1553825061863, name: "Thai Milk Tea", qty: "1", total_amount: 9500, toppings: 500}, {id: 1553825061863, name: "Thai Milk Tea", qty: "1", total_amount: 9500, toppings: 500}]

let res = arr.slice(1)
console.log(res);
```

### Using Spread Operator And Destructuring Assignment

```js
let arr = [{id: 1553825061863, name: "Thai Milk Tea", qty: "1", total_amount: 9500, toppings: 500}, {id: 1553825061863, name: "Thai Milk Tea", qty: "1", total_amount: 9500, toppings: 500}, {id: 1553825061863, name: "Thai Milk Tea", qty: "1", total_amount: 9500, toppings: 500}]

const [,...rest] = arr
console.log(rest);
```

Answer (score 0):

the simple way to remove one array index form  array using

```
var ar = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three'];
ar.shift(); // returns "zero"
console.log( ar );
```

if array like this you can delete 0 index using the following command.

```
var ar = [
            {  id: 155382506003,  toppings: 500}, 
            {  id: 155382506002,  toppings: 100},
            {  id: 155382506001,  toppings: 200}
            ];
  ar.shift();
console.log( ar );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of Javascript objects. You can remove the first element by:

using `shift` function, for example:

```
var first = fruits.shift(); // remove Apple from the front
```

using `splice` function, for example - remove an element by index position:

```
var removedItem = fruits.splice(pos, 1); // this is how to remove an item
```

you can access value of an element by index, for example:

```
var first = fruits[0];
```

you can find value of a field by using `foreach`, for example:

```
fruits.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
    if (item.id === 1553825061863) {
        console.log(item, index);
    }
});
```